# JQuery.Post() call an action result in a controller, MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, post, partial, actionresult

I have looked around and unable to find an answer to my question. New to jquery and mvc3 so sorry if it is obvious.

```
$.post('@Url.Action("EditPost", "Task")', { "fc": document.getElementById("#myForm")});
```

I am trying to save changes to a row in and refreshing a partial view without posting back the whole page.

With the above line of code I am trying to execute an action result in the controller but it appears to be looking for a view called EditPost rather than a method called EditPost in the task controller, which is what I want to do. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you post the EditPost method signature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using like this:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("EditPost", "Task")', $('#myForm').serialize(), function(data){
    $('#form').children().remove().append(data);
}, 'html');
```

You ned to specify that the dataType it's returning is html (a partial view) and `document.getElementById("#myForm")` can't possibly get you anything because you don't use `#` unless you are using a jquery selector and even if you remove `#` you will get the form element and not it's content. So you use `$('#myForm').serialize()` to get all it's content serialized as a post or get data.

Comment: thanks guilherme the problem was coming from my form and not serializing it. The 404 WAS coming from the controller that I wanted to access, because the form values were null!

Comment: no problem, you can use that solution if your form has the values the method is asking for.

Answer (score 2):

> document.getElementById("#myForm") ????

If you want to submit an entire form using AJAX:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
            alert('success');            }
    });
    return false;
});
```

This assumes that your controller action takes an entire view model containing multiple properties to bind to from the values of the input fields of the form:

```
public ActionResult EditPost(MyViewModel model) 
{
    ...
}
```

or only the value of some input:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("EditPost", "Task")';
var fc = $('#fc').val();
$.post(url, { fc: fc }, function(result) {
    alert('success');
});
```

This assumes that your controller action takes `fc` as argument:

```
public ActionResult EditPost(string fc) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I can't test right now, but i'm 90% sure that even if you send the entire form with the `fc` argument the post will work with both actions, unless `fc` it's outside the form.